# Positioning two UITextFields side by side using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am new to `Autolayout`, so I am struggling to understand how to position two `UITextFields` side by side. E.g.:

[image]

I have tried a number of constraints, but I cannot figure out how to correctly position them. When running the app.

Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: Try pinning the top, left and bottom of the check in textfield to the superview. Pin the top, right and bottom of the check out textfield to superview. And the left constraint of check out to check in using the 'pin' button (bottom left of the storyboard), a box between two lines icon.

Comment: That worked! Can you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pinning the top, left and bottom of the check in textfield to the superview. Pin the top, right and bottom of the check out textfield to superview. And the left constraint of check out to check in using the 'pin' button (bottom left of the storyboard), a box between two lines icon.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to create a Stack View with these TextFields

[image]

You have the views like this now:

[image]

Now, you have to select the Constraints to the Stack View:

[image]

And then you only have to select `Fill Proportionally` in the Distribution:

[image]

Final result:

[image]